# Matching has_many association on two models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have a job which `has_many` categories
I have a business which `has_many` categories.

Currently I'm only assigning 1 category to both job and a business but this will change later which is why I've created the has_many association.

The categories assigned to businesses and jobs are from the same category table selected with a select menu with the intention of matching them.

If have a job, how can I find businesses that match the jobs category.

For example
`job = Job.find(1)`

```
> job.categories.first.name
 => "programmer"
```

If I want to find all Businesses listed that have the `programmer` category how can I do this?

I think I might need a join or include similar to this but I'm not sure how this should be written exactly.

`Business.includes(:categories).where(:categories == ...)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is almost right. This should work:

```
Business.joins(:categories).where(categories: {name: 'programmer'})
```

Or if you have multiple categories:

```
Business.joins(:categories).where(categories: {name: ['programmer', 'other']})
```